# Fastest way to initialize numpy array with values given by function

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I am mainly interested in ((d1,d2)) numpy arrays (matrices) but the question makes sense for arrays with more axes. I have function f(i,j) and I'd like to initialize an array by some operation of this function

```
A=np.empty((d1,d2))
for i in range(d1):
    for j in range(d2):
        A[i,j]=f(i,j)
```

This is readable and works but I am wondering if there is a faster way since my array A will be very large and I have to optimize this bit.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19459658/how-can-i-fill-a-numpy-structured-array-from-a-function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way is to use [`np.fromfunction`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfunction.html). Your code can be replaced with the line:

```
np.fromfunction(f, shape=(d1, d2))
```

[This is implemented](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.9.1/numpy/core/numeric.py#L1855) in terms of NumPy functions and so should be quite a bit faster than Python `for` loops for larger arrays.

Answer (score 0):

```
a=np.arange(d1)
b=np.arange(d2)
A=f(a,b)
```

Note that if your arrays are of different size, then you have to create a meshgrid:

```
X,Y=meshgrid(a,b)
A=f(X,Y)
```